# What is a "protuberant person"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I am having a hard time making sense of the word "*protuberant*" in this sentence from an [online article](http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/arts/la-et-cm-die-mommy-die-review-20180517-story.html). I have always understood that word to mean something along the lines of "bulging", "protruding," usually describing eyes. I have consulted several [dic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/protuberant)tion[aries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/protuberant), but can't seem to find anything beyond that. But it doesn't seem to be the case here. What does *protuberant* mean when describing a person? Someone with bulging eyes? Is that what it means here?

> Meanwhile, Angela is carrying on with **protuberant** tennis pro Tony Parker (Andrew Carter), who becomes the object of lust to both Edith and Angela's gay son, Lance (Tom DeTrinis).

Answer (score 1):

In Merriam-Webster's definition of [*protuberant*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/protuberant), **prominent** is given as a synonym.

This sounds like a more understandable word for the sentence.

In short, I would say that the tennis pro "stands out" in an obvious and unmistakable way.

Although it's only a guess, I would say that he's probably an extroverted and flamboyant character in the play the article is talking about.

Comment: Or he has a lot of bulging muscles and the writer is using an unusual description to emphasize that the tennis pro is a caricature.

Comment: This is the only way I can make sense of it, but I think it's a case of thesaurus overuse. That's not a normal way to use that word...